# How to shrinkwrap without losing sculpted details

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want my sculpted model to follow curvature of a sphere but after applying shrinkwrap modifier all the sculpted geometry gets lost (picture 1). How do I set the shrinkwrap modifier so the model only bends accordingly to chosen curvated surfaces? Is shrinkwrap even a correct tool for that? If not, what is the best method to achieve my needs? (I also attach my blend file)
Thanks a lot guys.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded your file and found a way to achieve the result you want.

You need to create a **lattice object** and give it enough subdivisions for it to be conformed to the surface of your sphere. Then put only the bottom half of one of your leaf inside the lattice.

[image: Here's the lattice object with the bottom half of your leaf inside]

[image: Top view]

Then you can use the **lattice modifier** on your leaf to reference the **lattice object** you just created. Finally, apply the **shrinkwrap modifier** to the **lattice object** and it works. Now, you just have to repeat the process for the second leaf. I should also inform you that I had to scale up your objects to make it work since they were very small.

This forum post helped me : https://blenderartists.org/t/project-object-onto-another-and-keep-the-thickness/600541/5

Here's the modified scene :

[image]

The Result :
[image: Lattice and Shrinkwrap]